# Exit a Python Program (From a Function) with a Successful Run Result

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, return, exit

I'm trying to exit a Python test case that I'm running with a successful run result.  I have a program that uses a function I created to see if a table contains an identifier.

```
def test_LogsIdentifiersApache(driver, url):
        loginToWebsite(driver, url).confirmLoginAndUnlocked()
        driver.get(url('/LogsPage/'))
        selectIdentifier(driver, "gdm-simple-greeter")
```

In that function [located in a different file], it searches the table for the identifier.  If it finds it, then it does a few other checks and returns to running the test case.  If it doesn't find the identifier in the table, then it sends a message to the screen notifying the tester that the identifier wasn't in the table & exits with a successful run.

```
def selectIdentifier(driver, identifier):
    << Code to search for identifier here >>

    # If identifier not found, print message to window & exit test case with successful run
    if isIdentifierPresent == False:
        print "\nNOTICE: IDENTIFIERS OBJECT \""+identifier+"\" NOT LISTED IN TABLE"
        return
```

Using 'return' worked fine when I had all the code within the test case.  Once I began creating functions, the test stopped exiting with a successful run.  I understand that 'return' makes it return to the test case and continue running, which is what I don't want.  Instead I would like to.. (1) Print the message that the identifier wasn't found and.. (2) exit out of this function [and the test case being ran] with a successful run & continue running the test suite.  How can I do this?  Also, this test case is being ran directly from a folder with the 'py.test' command rather than from a test suite file, if that matters.

Comment: Scenario has been updated, @alecxe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I find best is to define an Exceptions class:

```
class noIdentifier(Exception):
    pass
```

Now modify the code to look as such:

```
if isIdentifierPresent == False:
    print "\nNOTICE: IDENTIFIERS OBJECT \""+identifier+"\" NOT LISTED IN TABLE"
    raise noIdentifier("<Optional message>")
```

In the test suite, wrap the test case call in try except:

```
try:
    testCase()
except noIdentifier:
    pass
```

I'm sure there are other ways to do it. However I find this to be really convinient.

EDIT: To use the optional message,

```
try:
    testCase()
except noIdentifier as e:
    print e.message # or use print str(e)
```

Comment: Yes, raising an exception is a good way to do "multiple returns" in one go.

Comment: Okay, one more question.  When I tried this method and put an optional message in the with... raise noIdentifier("<<message here>>")... the message was not printed.  Any ideas as to why!?

Comment: @rwbyrd Edited my answer to use the message.

Comment: @Pallav Agarwal Thanks for your edit.  The change works smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

If you're in Python 3 you can use sys.exit() to get out. Something like this maybe?

```
if isIdentifierPresent == False:
    print "\nNOTICE: IDENTIFIERS OBJECT \""+identifier+"\" NOT LISTED IN TABLE"
else:
    print("Hooray!")
    sys.exit()
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, @Kernel_Panic.  A few issues with this:  (1) I need it to print the message & then exit the function [and test case located in a different file] if the identifier is not found similar to what I have shown above. (2) sys.exit() causes the test case to fail, which I don't want.

Comment: I would use `if not isIdentifierPresent:` instead of `if isIdentifierPresent == False:`